# The largest circle that encloses no points on a plane with points placed at $N$ random coordinates

Tags: geometry, pr.probability

I randomly scatter $N$ points on a bounded rectangular plane $P$ with dimensions $A \times B$.  To be more specific, for $N$ iterations, I choose a real number $x \in [0, A]$ and a real number $y \in [0, B]$, and place my point at the coordinates $(x, y)$.

Let $R$ be the radius of some circle I place somewhere on the plane $P$ that encloses no points.  What is the probability distribution for the maximum permissible size of $R$?

Note - I specified $P$ to be a rectangular plane but, please, let it be any shape you wish if you can answer my question.

Comment: Is your circle supposed to be contained in $P$, or is it just the centre that must be in $P$ (in which case you're just maximizing the minimum distance to the chosen points)?  In either case, it's very unlikely that you could get a useful closed form for general $N$.  

Comment: @Robert Israel The circle (handle boundary points as you wish) should be contained in $P$.  And you're probably right that there is unlikely to be a closed form expression.  What if, however, we make $P$ a larger circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest empty ball in a point set is known in the literature as the *dispersion*; see, for example, [this definition](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node203.html).  This was explored a bit in a previous MO question, "[Finding the most-isolated point in a high-dimensional cube](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98682/)."  Here is a paper that explores dispersion.  This could serve to forward-search in Google Scholar.  Or you could hope that Günter Rote, who is now participating in MO, will comment directly:

> Rote, Tichy.
>   "Quasi-Monte-Carlo methods and the dispersion of point sequences"
>   *Mathematical and Computer Modelling* 23 (1996), 9-23.
>   ([ACM link](http://dl2.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2275170))

See also the recent paper on largest empty rectangles:

> Dumitrescu, Jiang.
>   "On the largest empty axis-parallel box amidst $n$ points."
>   2012. ([PDF download](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/faculty/ad/tau2.pdf))